# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined in three.js in typescript

Tags: three.js, typescript

i have small problem with initialization of camera position in three.js . I write this project in typescript. The browser console returns me :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined . Here is my source code in app.ts file:

```
///<reference path="Lib/three.d.ts">
class Rendering {
    camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
    scene: THREE.Scene;
    renderer: THREE.CanvasRenderer;
    windowHalfX: number;
    windowHalfY: number;

    constructor() {
        this.windowHalfY = window.innerHeight/2;
        this.windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    }

    public init() {
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, this.windowHalfX / this.windowHalfY, 1, 1000);
        this.camera.position.y = 100; // HERE CONSOLE CANNOT READ POSITION PROPERTY
        this.camera.position.z = 200;
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize(this.windowHalfX*2, this.windowHalfY*2);
        container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(150, 150, 150);
        for (var i = 0; i < cubeGeometry.faces.length; i += 2) {

            var hex = Math.random() * 0xffffff;
            cubeGeometry.faces[i].color.setHex(hex);
            cubeGeometry.faces[i + 1].color.setHex(hex);

        }
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5 });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
        cube.position.y = 150;
        this.scene.add(cube);
    }
    public render() {
        this.camera.lookAt(this.scene.position);
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main cause of this error would be that you don't have the PerspectiveCamera JavaScript available...

If you downloaded the Three.JS zip file and included `three.js` - this isn't everything you need on your web page.

Your best bet is to use the minified three.js file that you will find here:

http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js

This bundles all of the individual components you'll need in one minified script, including your PerspectiveCamera.